# Video streaming on site

Tags: video, streaming-video

I'm unfamiliar with the Raspberry Pi. I want to perform a video translation on site. I have a Raspberry Pi and USB webcam.

Can you please write what I need to do to perform the video translation on site?Please include what kind of host buy, and what OS install on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Do you mean video conversion?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "translation" do you mean video streaming?
The simplest is to use motioneye which supports various cameras including the pi camera.

https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos

otherwise you can use use the picamera python interface to do what you will.

https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/index.html#